# How do I standardize the orientation of several PLY models in MeshLab?

Tags: meshlab

I have a bunch of .ply models of human faces. I want to open them one at a time in MeshLab, but each time in the same orientation. How do I reorient the planes in MeshLab so they better align with the faces?
In other words, I want to view each face in a standardized orientation, such as the Frankfort Horizontal Plane [image: picture attached]  parallel to the ground, so that when I go to filters --> normals, curvatures,
and orientation, --> transform: rotate and I rotate the faces about a fixed axis and center of rotation, each face is fixed so that the Frankfort Horizontal Plane is parallel to the ground.

Comment: Just to clarify, do all the models share the same initial orientation? In other words do you have to apply the same exact transformation to all the models or do you have to search the correct transformation for each model?

Comment: @ALoopingIcon Yes, all the models share the same initial orientation, so I would like to apply the same exact transformation to all the models.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to create a mlx script with the rotation you want to apply to all meshes.

1. Open your favorite head model in meshlab and manually apply the 'transform: rotate' filter that align the model in the desired orientation.
2. Click on menu 'filters' , 'current script' and save the script to a file named Frankfort.mlx
3. Exit from meshlab
4. For each ply file in your repository execute the command 'meshlabser -i file.ply -o newfile.ply -s Frankfort.mlx'. You can use one bash script, powershell script or bat file for that.