# How do I standardize the orientation of several PLY models, that are different from each other, in MeshLab?

Tags: orientation, mesh, normals, meshlab

This is the only question I found, that is somewhat similar to mine: [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63351240/how-do-i-standardize-the-orientation-of-several-ply-models-in-meshlab).
The biggest difference is that I want to find a way to orient mutiple .ply point clouds, that aren't oriented the same way after loading.
For example:
[image: First .ply Object]
The first .ply object from one room looks, without applying any filter, like a top-down view.
[image: Second .ply Object]
The second .ply object from another room looks, again without applying any filter, like a view from underground with a 180° degree spin added.

How can I unify the orientation of these two .ply objects?

The reason behind my question is that I need to apply the same filter on both (or even more) .ply objects and at least get useable results out of it. But the "Compute normals for point clouds" Filter, which is needed for applying the following "Surface Reconstruction: Screened Poisson"-Filter, wants a View Direction or View Position, which is difficult to find, if every .ply object is oriented differently.

Hopefully you understand what I'm asking and that you can help me. I'm, of course, open if you need more questions answered.

Comment: Would you accept one "non fully automatic" solution?

Comment: Any help is appreciated!